# What is the most elegant way to deal with sourced files that themselves source (relative) source files in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am editing a file like
`/path/to/file.txt`
 with vim, hence the current directory is
`/path/to`.

Now, I have a directory
`/other/path/to/vim/files`
that contains `sourceA.vim`. Also, there is a `sourceB.vim` file in
`/other/path/to/vim/files/lib/sourceB.vim`

In `sourceA.vim`, I want to source `sourceB.vim`, so I put a
`so lib/sourceB.vim`
into it.

Now, in my file.txt, I do a
`:so /other/path/to/vim/files/sourceA.vim`
which fails, because the sourcing system is obviously not prepared for relative path names along with sourcing from another directory.

In order to fix this, I put a
`execute "so " . expand("<sfile>:p:h") . "/lib/sourceB.vim"`
into `sourceA.vim` which does what I want.

However, I find the solution a bit clumsy and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to it.

I cannot put the sourceA.vim nor sourceB.vim into vim's `plugin` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could modify your runtimepath in your vimrc or elsewhere:

```
set runtimepath+=/other/path/to/vim/files
```

Then use :runtime instead of :source in your sourceA.vim file:

```
runtime lib/sourceB.vim
```

You can then use the same ":so /../../../sourceA.vim" command as before...